# Copy from Word and keep formatting in Redactor II

Tags: redactor

How can i copy and paste tables from a MS Word document into the new Redactor II and keep (a bit of) the formatting?

In my case it's about hundreds of technical tables that i need to copy into the cms (craft cms). When i copy&paste it, it loses the layout completely.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

In the end i used a word>html tool like: https://word2cleanhtml.com/